# Updating Lambda using CDK doesn't deploy latest image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Using the AWS C# CDK.
I get a docker image from an ECR repository & then create a lambda function using it.

The problem is that when I run the CDK, it clearly creates CloudFormation that updates the function. Within the AWS console, the latest image is then shown under "Image > Image URI". However the behaviour of my lambda clearly shows that the latest image has NOT been deployed.

If I click "Deploy New Image", leave everything as normal & click Save, my Lambda then shows that it is updating & then the behaviour of my lambda is as expected (latest image).

Unsure where I'm going wrong:

```
            var dockerImageCode = DockerImageCode.FromEcr(ecrRepositoryContainingImage);

            var dockerImageFunction = new DockerImageFunction(this,
                Constants.LAMBDA_ID,
                new DockerImageFunctionProps()
                {
                    Code = dockerImageCode,
                    Description = versionString,
                    Vpc = foundationStackVpc,
                    SecurityGroups = new ISecurityGroup[]
                    {
                        securityStackVpcSecurityGroup
                    },
                    Timeout = Duration.Seconds(30),
                    MemorySize = 512
                });
```

It is almost like, my lambda gets updated & shows that it is apparently pointing at the correct image within ECR. However the reality is, that it is not actually deployed.

Edit: A temporary fix is to ensure that rather than pushing a new `image:latest` image to ECR, I now call it `image:buildnumber`. It seems that even if the image in ECR is underlyingly different & cdk has supposedly updated the lambda image reference to the newly uploaded one in ECR, it doesn't actually redeploy/consider a change has occurred worthy of redeployment when the old image tag & new image tag are both named the same, in this case `latest`. Now since the build number will always be different & thus the new image tag will always be different to the previous one, this is deemed enough of a change for the lambda to be redeployed properly.

Comment: For the lambdas deployed from s3 it behaved the same way when I did not use s3 object version for an s3 bucket with versioning enabled. But I am curious what the solution is for ECR.

Comment: This behavior is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html): _"In Amazon ECR, if you reassign the image tag to another image, Lambda does not update the image version."_
So, it seems to me, there is no other way than redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

The tag: latest did not work for me also. I think an easy way is to use SSM in the CodeBuild

```
'aws ssm put-parameter --name FhrEcrImageTagDemo --type String --value ${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION} --overwrite'
```

Then in CDK lambda

```
code: aws_lambda.Code.fromEcrImage(
          aws_ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryName(
            this,
            'id',
            'ecrRepositoryName',
          ),
          {
            tag: aws_ssm.StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(
              this, 
              'parameterName'
            )
          }
        )
```

Another potential solution is using the exported variables and override parameters in this example [class TagParameterContainerImage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-ecs.TagParameterContainerImage.html). It works for ecs but not sure for lambda and ecr.

Comment: This shouldn't be included as an answer as this would not resolve the issue. Kindly use the comment section just below the initial question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

When using API `fromEcr`, you can specify `EcrImageCodeProps` with specified image tag.

See [doc](http://%22class%20DockerImageCode%20%C2%B7%20AWS%20CDK%22%20https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.DockerImageCode.html#static-fromwbrecrrepository-props) for detail.

Comment: I'm unsure how you propose that this would solve the problem? The `tag` is set as `latest` by default on `EcrImageCodeProps`. So if you overwrite the image tagged as `latest` within your ECR repository, then update your lambda, it still doesn't re-deploy the lambda as it thinks the image hasn't changed since the tag is the same.

Comment: Using `latest` as tag is NOT a best practice, which is evil and always error prone. The recommended way is always tagging the image with immutable tag like smever, timestamp, even buildid. Then redeploy the stack. Of course, you have different approaches to manage the tag updating, for example, manual update with PR process, fetching the tag version from configuration before synthesizing your cdk app. Hope make it clear.

Comment: This is a problem for any kind of floating tag (such as `stable` or `net6` or `1.x`), which makes it difficult to build deployment pipelines that follow security updates.