# Terraform: Lambda Change Based On Image Change

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, docker-registry

I'm trying to create a Lambda with Terraform based on an docker image and I want that Lambda to get pushed every time I create a new image. I'm trying to use depends_on inside lambda, but it doesn't work, Lambda just stay in the same state as before. Any other solution or any way to make it work?

This is the code I have right now:

```
resource "docker_registry_image" "registry_image" {
  name = docker_image.image.name
  triggers = {
    dir_sha1 = sha1(join("", [for f in fileset("../AWS/", "**") : filesha1("../AWS/${f}")]))
  }
}

resource "docker_image" "image" {
  name = "${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:latest"
  triggers = {
    dir_sha1 = sha1(join("", [for f in fileset("../AWS/", "**") : filesha1("../AWS/${f}")]))
  }
  build {
    context    = "../AWS/"
    dockerfile = "Dockerfile"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository" "repo" {
  name         = "repo"
  force_delete = true
}

resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "repo_policy" {
  repository = aws_ecr_repository.repo.name
  policy     = <<EOF
  {
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Set the permission for ECR",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
          "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
          "ecr:BatchGetImage",
          "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
          "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
          "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
          "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
          "ecr:PutImage",
          "ecr:UploadLayerPart"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
EOF
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda1" {
  depends_on    = [docker_image.image]
  function_name = "lambda1"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
  image_uri     = "${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:latest"
  image_config {
    command           = ["lambda1.handler"]
    working_directory = "/var/task"
  }
  package_type = "Image"
  memory_size  = 2048 # Min 128 MB and the Max 10,240 MB, there are some files of 300 MB
  timeout      = 180
  environment {
    variables = {
      TZ = "Europe/Madrid"
    }
  }
}
```

### Update

It seems that it is a issue of Amazon CDK. I recommend you to read
this thread: [updating-lambda-using-cdk-doesnt-deploy-latest-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187057/updating-lambda-using-cdk-doesnt-deploy-latest-image).